# Why isn't my firebase listener firing when the app is offline and initialized offline

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I've setup a listener on my database that is only failing to respond in a weird offline scenario.

On setup I'm adding a listener to a database that should fire anytime there's an update...

```
let mySpots = self.databaseRefSpots.child("users").child(globalMasterUser.userUID).child("type").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
    //code that should be executed when there's an update.
```

Once the user takes some action that should get saved, it's saved to the firebase database using...

```
annotationdb.child("type").setValue("Feature")
annotationdb.child("properties").setValue(propDict)
annotationdb.child("geometry").setValue(["type":"Point"])
annotationdb.child("geometry").child("coordinates").setValue(coordinates)
```

This code works whenever the user is online, and when a user starts the app online and goes offline.

But, if the listener is created when the app is initialized in an offline state, it looks like the listener is setup successfully, but after my setValue's are called, the listener isn't called.  If I turn the data connection on, at that point my listeners are called with the values I set with setValue.

Any idea why the listeners aren't firing in this offline state?

I've tried stepping through the firebase code to see if the listener is getting hit and it's not.  I've tried creating separate listeners to catch this scenario and they wont fire either.